# DRF Serializers : Ordering on StringRelatedField

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have `ModelSerializer` which has a field from a chained model like below.

```
owner_login = StringRelatedField(source='resource.owner.login_id', read_only=True)
```

I want to add dynamic sorting on this field, How do I do that?

**View**

```
class ProfileApplicationLogs(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = ResourceLog
    serializer_class = ProfileApplicationLogSerializer
    ordering_fields = ('run_remediate', )
    ordering = ('-run_remediate',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        id = self.kwargs['userid']
        days = self.kwargs['days']
        now = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)

        return ResourceLog.objects
                          .filter(Q(actual_start_time__isnull = True) |
                                  Q(actual_start_time__gt=earlier))\
                          .extra(tables=["cpe_resource_mgmt"],
                                 where=["resource_mgmt_id = cpe_resource_mgmt.id",
                                        "cpe_resource_mgmt.owner_id IN ( \
                                         select id from cpe_user \
                                         where is_active='Y' \
                                         connect by prior id = parent_id start with id = % s)"], params=[id])\ 
                                # .order_by('-actual_end_time')  // earlier I was doing this.
```

Comment: Ordering should be done at the view level, see [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter) how.

Comment: @GabrielMuj Thanks, I got it. but documentation doesn't say how do I order related fields. Can you please point me to the right doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StringRelatedField` is just a representation. You will need to make the order inside your view:

```
class YourListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YourSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('resource__owner__login_id', )
    ordering = ('resource__owner__login_id',)  # add this only if you want to use it as default ordering
```

If you don't make that as default ordering, then your request should contain the `ordering` query parameter like this

`http://example.com/api/yourmodel?ordering=resource__owner__login_id`

Comment: somehow data I get is same for `ordering=resource__owner__login_id` and `ordering=-resource__owner__login_id`. 
No ordered data, debugging that.

Comment: Can you post also your view?

Comment: Please see, I updated the code, Gabriel. Though `actual_end_time` is not related field, its in `ResourceLog` model only. but that is not working too

Comment: Did you add also `filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)` in the view? I don't see it.

Comment: Nope, let me try adding that.

Comment: You man, It worked after adding `filter_backends`, let me try related fields now.

Comment: What should I specify in `ordering_fields`? `ordering_fields = '__all__'` is okay or I should have to specify all fields including related field by `__` notation?

Comment: I had to specify fields, `__all__` did not work. Anyway thank you Gabriel. :-)

Comment: I think `ordering_fields = '__all__'` works only for fields on the model, not relation, so you need to add them manually.

Comment: May be, I did not find documentation saying so.